# How to convert string to date object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a date string like '`2019-06-12 12:02:12 232`',how to convert to date using Javascript?

```
Date date = Date.parse('2019-06-12 12:02:12 232').format('yyyy-MM-dd dd:HH:ss SSS');
```

I want to compare two date to calculate the minisecond in Javascript.Any suggestion?How could I tweak my date string?The date string was generate is server side using Java:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss SSS");
String dateTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.of("+8")).format(formatter);
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript) does not contain minisecond,if no minisecond,Date.parse could solved the problem.My question is precise contain more detail operation of Javascript Date.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the *wrong* class to be using in Java for that purpose. I cannot think of any situation where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is the right thing to do. That class cannot represent a moment as it purposely *lacks any concept of time zone* or offset-from-UTC. This is explained in the class Javadoc. Instead, to capture the current moment, use `Instant` for UTC, use `OffsetDateTime` for some other offset, or use `ZonedDateTime` for a particular time zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
let date_string = "2019-06-12 12:02:12 232"
let [y,M,d,h,m,s] = date_string.split(/[- :]/);
let yourDate =  new Date(y,parseInt(M)-1,d,h,parseInt(m),s);
console.log(`yourDate ${yourDate}`);
```

[In addition, avoid using `Date.parse()` method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

**UPDATE:**

By using the above approach, you will avoid some strange bugs as described in the above link. However, it is possible to use [a great library `Moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

In addition, you could check if a date is valid:

```
moment("whether this date is valid").isValid(); // OUTPUT: false
```

Comment: I have to write my own method to convert by hande? no system function?maybe I should use unix timestamp?@StepUp

Comment: @Dolphin please, see my updated answer

Comment: Ok. I understand.I would learn moment.js lib to handle the problem.Thank you!

Comment: @Dolphin I am glad to help you!